# How can I orient?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

How can I orient the mobile a page with an image that looks smaller when it's vertical, bigger (original size) when it's horizontal?

The code and image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

               <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ball" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

See Image for better Understanding
[image]

Comment: Executive summary Answer: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: you should make different layouts for landscape and portrait and then you can design them separately. More Info: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thank you so muck, I learned for changing drawable-xxxx